# Translate and import data into a MySQL DB

Tags: mysql

this is my situation:
I work with huge CSV files (>2GB) that I need to import into a MySQL DB. These CSVs contain text that I would like to translate in order to understand the content. At the moment I am accessing data online through a tool of my company and I translate the text with a Google Translate extension.
What would be a smarter way to do it? I accept any solution.

Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: Google Translate is a poor traslator. I would recommend various other translators depending on language.

Comment: For 2Gb CSV files, I would recommend breaking them into smaller files of ~500Mb or so for easier handling. You can do this manually or from the source data

Comment: Yes I already break them into 200MB files. I don't need to have a perfect translation, so Google Translator works fine, but of course it just translates the content of a web page... I wonder if there is a better way of doing this